# Verizon Wireless Mobile Broadband Connect w/ Linux Netbook

Tags: linux, 3g

I currently have a Blackberry Curve 8330 with Verizon Wireless. I'm considering activating their Mobile Broadband Connect service. I'd like to use this service with my Asus eeePC 1000 netbook running Ubuntu 9.04. Is it possible to access VZW's broadband through my Blackberry without using the VZAccess Manager software? What, if any, additional software will I need on my netbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limited testing confirms that **[Berry4all](http://www.berry4all.com)** works with my setup listed above. Linux installation worked well when following the steps listed [here](http://www.berry4all.com/install).